# Express route that matches all /admin pages

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I am trying to define a route in express that matches any `/admin` requests like `/admin/users`, `/admin/settings` or `/admin/profile/user` , not including `/admin` or `/admin/` ,as they are meant for login, to check if the connection is https and if the admin is logged in.

I've tried various regex such as:

```
/admin/:var()
/admin/.*
/admin/*
/admin/var(*)
```

But none seem to work.For the routing I am using:

```
app.use('/admin/:var(.{1,})',function(req,res,next){
    res.send("hello world");
    console.log("matched "+req.params.var);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A route like this:

```
app.use('/admin/:more', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(`req.path: ${req.path}`);
    // check admin login and https here
    next();
});
```

does not match `/admin` or `/admin/`, but does match `/admin/anythingelse` and `/admin/anythingelse/andmore` which is what I think you asked for.

Comment: Yes it works. It is however very strange, I tried it before and didn't work. Tried it now and didn't work in chrome. However when I switched to incognito mode it worked. Without being in incognito mode it keeps redirecting me to /admin/home which is supposed to happen only if I call `next`, and I don't

Comment: @AnduHD - A redirect has to be coming from your own code somewhere else.  Not anything we can help you with here without seeing the code causing the redirect.  Nothing here does a redirect.  The connection to incognito mode makes me think you have a cookie that some of your code is seeing and doing something different because it exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just found some info about chrome caching redirects and I guess that was the strange behaviour.